# SaaS application subscription model (mobile apps on React Native, and Web on ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, react-native, saas

I want to develop a [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)-based application.
I know the basics and have a product in mind too.
But I do not the how to develop an architecture to make the SaaS app. I want a step-by-step guide with me.

Subscription Model

Technologies: Mobile apps on React Native, and Web on ASP.NET MVC with an [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) frontend Bootstrap.
Note: I do not want anyone else to develop it for me. I will develop the SaaS by myself because I am also a software developer, but I have never developed a SaaS application.